# Custom names in a named tuple definition becoming default names "Item1" and "Item2"

Tags: c#, valuetuple

I am creating a list of named tuples. I propulate this list using the add method but after this process, I realize that the tuples' members have lost their custom names being accessible only by "Item1", "Item2"...

I am using .NET framework version 4.6.2, C# 7.3

```
private static List<(string name, string url)> GetItemsNamesAndUrls(IEnumerable<MyItems> itemsList)
    {
        List<(string name, string url)> result = new List<(string name, string url)>();
        foreach (var item in itemsList)
        {
            result.Add((name: item.Name, url: GetItemUrlFromName(item.Name)));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

MyItem class is very simple:

```
class MyItems
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

After the result list being populated, I expect to be able to access the named tuples members by the custom names, not using Item1 and Item2.

Comment: Could you post code from "MyItems" class ?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/26/c-7-series-part-1-value-tuples/

Comment: Can you add a simple code example to reproduce the problem? Because this worked: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkIG2.png

Comment: Yes, it seems to be it is working in a console application. So, maybe the problem is not related with that code itself, but with what I do with the result of that code. The returned list is passed as part of a view model to an MVC view. There, in the view, I get the exception with the following information:

Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''System.ValueTuple<string,string>' does not contain a definition for 'url''

Answer (score 0):

Tuple value names equate to method variables. They are only valid where declared.

Using your `GetItemsNamesAndUrls` method, this is valid code:

```
var l = GetItemsNamesAndUrls(itemsList);
var t1 = l[0];
var n = t1.name;
var u = t1.url;
(string x, string y) t2 = t1;
var x = t2.x;
var y = t2.y;
var (a, b) = t1;
var c = t1 == t2; // true
```